# change visibility of button on customtask

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

I actually have a custom task pane on my Outlook add-in that works very well. My problem is that I would like to change visibility of one button presents on my customTaskPane, but I don't know how to do that in my thisAddin.

The part of code where I try to do that. Perhaps it's more comprehensible.

```
if (person.Role == 1)
                        {
                            //Person is SysAdmin no Button display
                            //How could I change state of my button ??
                        }
                        else if (person.Role == 2)
                        {
                            //Person is ServiceAdmin display refused button

                        }
                        else if (person.Role == 3)
                        {
                            //Person is ServiceAgent display refused and considered button when mail is 
                            //not considered and respond button where mail is considered

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I put the solution if anyone had the same problem.

I put the code in userControl.cs instead of thisAddin, and save the "person.Role" information on the currentInformation to retrieve it on the userControl.cs